# Como criar sistema de pagamento web, usando PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pagamento-online

Gostaria de criar um e-commerce, porém não possuo muito conhecimento á respeito.
E ainda tenho a seguinte duvida.
        Como criar um sistema de pagamento via boleto ou cartão, existe algum framework ou API, que ofereça o serviço?, caso exista como anexar ao site?.
         Como lançar boletos?, existe algum framework para auxiliar na criação de boletos em pdf, esses devem possuir uma validação fiscal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bem, são várias perguntas, vamos lá:

> Como criar um sistema de pagamento via boleto ou cartão, existe algum
>   framework ou empresa que ofereça o serviço?

Via boleto, é fácil, fale com seu gerente para que ele forneça alguns números que você utilizará. Alguns bancos fornecem o código de exemplo para criar o boleto, fiz uma vez com a Caixa Econômica Federal. Você pode também procurar uma solução externa, cheguei a ver mas não usei: http://boletophp.com.br/. Os boletos normalmente tem um prazo para confirmar o recebimento depois de pagos e não espere ser tão curto como o de lojas grandes, quando eu fiz por exemplo levava de 2 a 5 dias dependendo de um monte de coisas.

Cartão é mais complicado, você fala com a operadora de cartão da qual vai receber, normalmente envolve transação, você envia um pacote de dados, o servidor da operadora responde, você envia outro confirmando ou com algum outro dado e, por fim, recebe a finalização.

> , caso exista como anexar ao site?.

No caso de boletos, grave a identificação do boleto nas informações de pagamentos em aberto, no caso de cartão, normalmente o pagamento é no ato, mas pode haver tratamento diferente que eu não conheça, vai depender da operadora. Você pode usar o "nosso número" e o "número do documento" para identificar o boleto. O "nosso número" é incomum para identificar cada boleto, mas no meu caso eu tive que usá-lo.

> Como lançar boletos?

Envia os valores para a aplicação que os gera e ela gera, sem nenhuma complicação, mas também não há registro, você deve registrar em seu código.

> , existe algum framework para auxiliar na criação de boletos em pdf,
>   esses devem possuir uma validação fiscal?

Sim, exemplo na resposta à primeira pergunta, mas não são em PDF, não é necessário. Também existem soluções pagas, super fácil achar no Google, procurando "boleto online" aparecem várias soluções. Não precisa validação fiscal, mas é recomendável uma palavra do seu gerente. Por exemplo, para o que eu desenvolvi para uso na caixa, geramos três boletos junto com o gerente e testamos se estava tudo válido.

Answer (score 4):

Cara, tenta utilizar os serviços como o pagseguro ou o mercadopago, nele você deixa a questão de recebimento (cartões, boletos, etc) por conta deles, e ambos fornecem um webservice para acompanhar a situação dos seus pagamentos e os scripts necessários para integração.

Comment: No caso da comunicação com estes serviços, tem alguma API para auxiliar ? é feito via url ?, é pago?  e por ultimo tem algum tutorial ensinando a usar ?

Comment: Ambos os serviços cobram taxas por recebimento, mas com eles é possível vender com boleto, cartão de crédito, etc e receber a vista.

PagSeguro: https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/index.html

Mercado Pago:
https://developers.mercadopago.com/?lang=pt_BR

Answer (score 2):

falaram do pagseguro e mercado pago, mas esqueceram do [PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/br/home) e [TrayCheckout](https://www.traycheckout.com.br/), eu acho que é mais negocio terceirizar essa questão com esses gateways de pagamento, as vezes nos sites destas empresas tem lá uma sessão de desenvolvedores, que explica como utilizar a api de seus serviços. o paypal por exemplo está aqui nesse link [paypal dev](https://developer.paypal.com/).

Quanto aos framework, utilize qualquer um que se sinta a vontade, frameworks são genéricos para praticamente qualquer sistema, você só precisa encontrar um bom [gateway de pagamento](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_de_pagamento) e se comunicar com as api's utilizando um framework, ou faz na mão, exemplo de frameworks: [zend](http://framework.zend.com/), [codeigniter](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter), [cake](http://cakephp.org/)...

Comment: Se é para dar mais opções tem também o Moip e o BCash (antigo Pagamento Digital).